# How do I properly save and use my sessionID in the browser for subsequent requests with with passport.js' local strategy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, next.js, passport.js

I've been attempting to implement a passport.js based authentication system with the local strategy in my express.js server which provides service to my next.js application.

A problem I've identified is that while I am indeed receiving a 'Set-Cookie' header when I login through my login route, the session ID associated will not save to the browser, I am convinced this may be the root of my problem.

These are the headers I received from my server after logging in.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 132
ETag: W/"84-tJ1ZGbGdYme59InUWSh8Rb86kz8"
Set-Cookie: connect.sid=s%3ARh7ykakijj4rytD-nf50O7SvhD2zE0KE.%2Bo2POSH6kZ%2BIvi6IoH9Jz8Do%2BR8QTXmzapfiRm1b9KM; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 02 Jun 2023 03:27:23 GMT; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
Date: Fri, 02 Jun 2023 02:27:23 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
```

This is my login route:

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/invalid' }), (req, res) => {

    try {
        // req.login(req.user, (err) => {
        //     if (err) { throw new Error(err); }
        //     res.json({
        //         timestamp: new Date().getTime(),
        //         message: "User authenticated successfully",
        //         authenticated: true,
        //         route: 'http://localhost:3000/profile'
        //     });
        // });
        res.json( // Ive tried the first block and this block and both together
            {
                timestamp: new Date().getTime(),
                message: "User authenticated successfully",
                authenticated: true,
                route: 'http://localhost:3000/profile'
            }
        )
```

And my handleSubmit function:

```
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8443/login', {
            username: formData.username,
            password: formData.password,
            withCredentials: true
        })

        if (response.data) {
            // TODO: prefetch?
            console.log(response)
            router.push(router.query.from || '/')
        }

    }
```

In addition to this, my validate route is not functional which I presume is because I have no session ID from the browser for the server to validate.

This is my validate route:

```
router.get('/validate', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.headers)
    console.log(req.isAuthenticated())
    try {
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {

            res.json({
                timestamp: new Date().getTime(),
                message: "Session validated",
                authenticated: true,
                route: 'http://localhost:3000/profile'
            })
        }

        else {
            res.json({
                timestamp: new Date().getTime(),
                message: "Session invalid",
                authenticated: false,
                route: 'http://localhost:3000/login'
            })
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})
```

And my getServerSideProps function which im just testing for validation for now:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {


    try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8443/validate', { withCredentials: true })

        if (response.data.authenticated) {
            console.log("redirecting")
            return {
                redirect: {
                    destination: '/',
                    permanent: false,
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log("not redirecting")
            return {
                props: {
                    authenticated: false,
                },

            }
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log("error")
        return {
            props: {
                authenticated: false,
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Here are my session/app configurations:

```
const app = express()
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(session({
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: 'SECRET', 
    store: store,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 1, // 1 hour
        sameSite: 'none',
        secure: false, // TODO: Change this to true in production
    },

}))
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true,
}))
```

And my passport.js configuration as well if that helps:

```
const store = MongoStore.create({
    mongoUrl: process.env.MONGO_URI,
    collectionName: 'sessions',
    ttl: 60 * 60 * 1,
    autoRemove: 'native',
})




passport.use(new LocalStrategy('local', async (username, password, done) => {
    try {

        User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
            if (err) { return done(err); }
            if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
            if (!user.comparePassword(password)) { return done(null, false, { message: "Wrong Passwword" }); }
            return done(null, user);
        });

    }

    catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
    }
}
));



passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.userID);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (user, done) => {
    try {
        User.findOne(user.userID, async (err, user) => {
            if (err) { return done(err); }


            if (!user) { return done(null, false); }


            return done(null, user);
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
    }
});
```

One test that may have honed in on the issue was my postman testing, the cookie was saved and my sessions/authentication worked as planned however I deduce that postman might have different method of saving my cookie compared to my browser but I could be wrong.

I also attempted a small example in which I was able to verify I was getting the headers I was looking for in a node environment:

```
const axios = require('axios')

const test = async () => { 
    const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8443/login', {
            username: 'LaElijah',
            password: 'pass',
            withCredentials: true
        })

    const data = await response.headers
    console.log(data)
}


test()
```

Even still, I cant figure out why I'm not storing this sessionID and how I can use it in subsequent requests, any help will be greatly appreciated!